# SFML С++ вставка музыки

Tags: c++

Я только начала изучать SFML.

- Почему не воспроизводит звук?

  ```
  #include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

   int main()
   { sf::Music music;//создаем объект музыки
   music.openFromFile("music.ogg");//загружаем файл
   music.play();//воспроизводим музыку

   return 0;
  }
  ```
- Скажите пожалуйста можно ли вставить видео или гифку в программу с помощью SFML?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
sf::SoundBuffer buffer;            
    if (!buffer.loadFromFile("music.ogg"))          
        return -1;
```

Comment: запускается но не воспроизводит звук((((((((((

Comment: @Sofia а файл этой музыки есть в директории с готовой программой? И вообще, поддерживается ли на компьютере этот формат?

Answer (score 0):

У меня так работает:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Music music;//создаем объект музыки
    music.openFromFile("Audio.wav");//загружаем файл
    music.play();//воспроизводим музыку
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Музыка работает а в коде со звуком чтото проблемы. Возможно SFML неправильно установлен - [Как подключить SFML к Visual Studio C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1KJHD2-N0M&t=10s)

Comment: Это ответ на вопрос ТС?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте *.wav файлы для проигрывания музыкальных треков. Я пробовал подключать *.мр3 файлы, но программа не компилирует игру и выдает ошибку компиляции.

Comment: В вопросе же `.ogg`. Во вторых, как это может быть ошибкой компиляции? Может ошибка во время выполнения?

Comment: Да, у меня была ошибка при компиляции мр3 файла. Я просто перегнал мр3 файл в wav. Также я указываю полный путь к файлу для проверки доступа. Если ок, правлю на путь из корня проекта.

Comment: Не понял. Компилируется ведь код, а mp3 загружается после запуска программы, нет?

Comment: Когда запускаем программу в отладчике, то до компиляции не доходим, т.к. дебагер выдет ошибку: не поддерживается формат файла.

Comment: Звучит как бессмыслица, уж извините. Дебаггер работает только с уже скомпилированной программой.

Comment: R2D2 -X SFML поддерживает форматы аудио файлов WAV, OGG / Vorbis и FLAC. Из-за проблем с лицензией MP3 не поддерживается.